# aireplay-ng --> 'device or ressource busy' + crash

Tags: ubuntu, airmon-ng

Hello I am on Ubuntu and I have a problem with the aireplay-ng command: When i do the command  `aireplay-ng -0 0 -a $bssid -c $targetid wlp3s0`in the terminal I have the error message 'resource or device busy' and my computer crash so I have to force it to shutdown.
Even if I try with a bssid or a target id which doesn't exist I have this result.
I have the same when I try  `airmon-ng start wlp3s0` so I think it's because of my interface but I searched and I can't find anything that can help me

Comment: Does `$bssid` or `$targetid` contain a space?

Comment: Are you using wlp3s0 for your connection to the rest of your network?

Comment: @roaima        No in fact I didn't write $bssid and $targetid but directly the mac adress. If I did this it's to hide the mac adress of devices

Comment: Yes I am using wlp3s0.    PS: sorry if my english is wrong I don't speak english verry well.

Comment: You can't use the same interface for your network connection at the same time as using it for monitoring